# Error while installing libc++

Tags: archlinux, libc++, manjaro

I am a manjaro user. I wanted to install discord with AUR but I needed to install libc++... But there is an error while installing this package.

```
Command: ['/tmp/yaourt-tmp-lulz/aur-libc++/src/build/projects/libcxx/test/std/localization/locale.categories/facet.numpunct/locale.numpunct.byname/Output/thousands_sep.pass.cpp.exe']
Exit Code: -6
Standard Error:
--
thousands_sep.pass.cpp.exe: /tmp/yaourt-tmp-lulz/aur-libc++/src/llvm/projects/libcxx/test/std/localization/locale.categories/facet.numpunct/locale.numpunct.byname/thousands_sep.pass.cpp:66: int main(): Assertion `np.thousands_sep() == sep' failed.
--

Compiled test failed unexpectedly!
********************
Testing Time: 7029.08s
********************
Failing Tests (3):
    libc++ :: std/localization/locale.categories/category.monetary/locale.money.get/locale.money.get.members/get_long_double_fr_FR.pass.cpp
    libc++ :: std/localization/locale.categories/category.monetary/locale.money.put/locale.money.put.members/put_long_double_fr_FR.pass.cpp
    libc++ :: std/localization/locale.categories/facet.numpunct/locale.numpunct.byname/thousands_sep.pass.cpp

  Expected Passes    : 5748
  Expected Failures  : 7
  Unsupported Tests  : 116
  Unexpected Failures: 3

4 warning(s) in tests.
FAILED: projects/libcxx/test/CMakeFiles/check-cxx 
cd /tmp/yaourt-tmp-lulz/aur-libc++/src/build/projects/libcxx/test && /usr/bin/python2.7 /tmp/yaourt-tmp-lulz/aur-libc++/src/build/./bin/llvm-lit -sv /tmp/yaourt-tmp-lulz/aur-libc++/src/build/projects/libcxx/test
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ignore the tests, ignore the tests. Locale tests fail for all sorts of reasons. In your case it's likely that your linux distribution has different locale definitions than the tests expect. This happens a lot.

Comment: how can I ignore the tests ?

Comment: @ErwanROUSSELwith --nocheck